# malloc in c but use 2d syntax...compile a no go of answer

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, malloc

I was trying to find a way to allocate a single block of memory, but use multi-dimensional syntax, and I found the exact thing I was looking for on SO.

[malloc in C, but use multi-dimensional array syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144132/malloc-in-c-but-use-multi-dimensional-array-syntax/3144577#3144577)

But after cut/pasting the code there:

```
  int (*MAGICVAR)[200] = malloc(400 * sizeof *MAGICVAR);
    MAGICVAR[20][10] = 3;
```

This error message pops up: "An array of type void * cannot be used to initialize an entity of type int(*)[200]"
And it didn't help to cast the malloc to "int *" or "int **"

I'm using vs2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use a C compiler and not a C++ compiler to compile C code, second, if you have to use a C++ compiler, cast the return value of `malloc` to the declared type,

```
int (*MAGICVAR)[200] = (int(*)[200])malloc(400*sizeof *MAGICVAR);
```

Comment: +1, but really iff he has to use a C++ compiler, he should write C++ and not C. So it then would be `new int[400][200]` or something like this.

Comment: Yes, must use C++ compiler.  But using that cast "(int(*)[200])" was what I could not get.      No idea why this question got down voted...but at least it got answered! Thank you.