# Simple c malloc

Tags: c, malloc

this doesn't work:

```
void function(char* var)
{
    var = (char*) malloc (100);
}

int main()
{
    char* str;
    function(str);
    strcpy(str, "some random string");
    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

this does:

```
void function(char* var)
{
    //var = (char*) malloc (100);
}

int main()
{
    char* str;
    //function(str);
    str = (char*) malloc (100);
    strcpy(str, "some random string");
    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Why?

Comment: When you say "doesn't work," it would be helpful to know *what* about it doesn't work. Details are good.

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to mention it. It compiles, but when I run it I get a Segmentation Fault.

Comment: Your code works exactly as it supposed to. If you think something "doesn't work", you have to explain what it is. Without it your question makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Since it compiles, I am guessing the "function" vs. "funtion" typo in the code pasted above is just for the question sake. Probably should go ahead and correct it though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to pass the address of the pointer to assign the address you want *inside* the function, otherwise you are just passing a copy of it:

```
void function(char** var)
{
    *var = malloc (100);
}

int main()
{
    char* str;
    function(&str);
    strcpy(str, "some random string");
    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a pointer to pointer as a parameter for that, `char **`.
When you pass a pointer as a parameter, it gets copied, so what you get inside the function is just another pointer pointing to the same place.

You need to receive a `char **` and do:

```
my_alloc_fun(void **ptr){
    *ptr= malloc(size);
}
void *myptr;
my_alloc_fun(&myptr);
```

This way, you get the address of the pointer inside the function, so that you can make the original pointer to point to the newly allocated memory.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `function(str)`, you are passing the value of `str` to `function`.  This value is some uninitialized garbage value because you haven't set it to anything in `main`, but that's not the problem.

The problem is that `function` has its own pointer, `var`, into which it puts that garbage value so that one could say `var points to the same thing (garbage) that str points to`.  However, they are not the same variable.  They are two distinct variables, and changing `var` has no effect on `str`.

When you say `var = (char*) malloc (100);`, you are allocating memory somewhere and then telling `var` to point to it.  Now `var` points to a different location than `str`.  Immediately you return from that function, losing `var` and the location of that memory.  This by the way is a memory leak.

When you return back to `main`, `str` is as it ever was - pointing to garbage.

A numerical example:

```
char *str;     // str -> 0xfeedface   (garbage)
function(str);

// inside 'function', an initialization like this occurs
char *var = str;  // var -> 0xfeedface (same garbage)
var = (char*) malloc (100); // var -> 0x12341234 (alloc'd memory)
return;

// back in 'main'
strcpy(str, "some random string"); // str still points to 0xfeedface!
```

To do this properly, you need to change `str`s value.  This means `function` needs a pointer to `str`, or a **pointer to a pointer**.

```
void function(char **var)
{
   *var = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
}

int main()
{
   char *str;
   function(&str);
   strncpy(str, "some random string", 99);
   ...
   free(str);  // important in general
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are just like any other variable; the difference is only in what their value represents.  Whereas a `double` has a value that represents a double-precision floating point number, and an `int` has a value that represents a signed integer, a pointer has a value that represents the location of another variable.

Pointers themselves are still passed by-value to other functions; so your example doesn't work for exactly the same reason that this analagous function doesn't work:

```
void function(int var)
{
    var = 100;
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    function(num);
    printf("%d\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

The answer in both cases is the same: When `function()` changes the value of the parameter `var`, it is changing only its local copy of that - it isn't changing the variable within `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to [C Programming: malloc() inside another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838038/c-programming-malloc-inside-another-function/2838207#2838207) for an explanation about how to think about this.