# Copying 2D arrays in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to copy 2D array from CPU to GPU.From host side i'm sending base pointer of 2D array,P is number of elements in one dimension

```
 int *d_a;

 cudaMalloc(d_a,P*P*sizeof(int));

 copyKernelHostToDevice((int(*)[P])d_a,(int(*)[P])hAligned_a);

 copyKernelHostToDevice((int(*)[P])d_b,(int(*)[P])hAligned_b);


 inline void copyKernelHostToDevice(int (*A)[P],int (*B)[P]){

      for(int i=0;i<P;i++)
      cutilSafeCall(cudaMemcpyAsync(A[i],B[i],P*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

}
```

but above code is giving me runtime error

cudaSafeCall() Runtime API error 11: invalid argument.

Am I missing something?
P is significantly large...arnd 2048

Comment: If you are getting an invalid argument error, it probably means that B[i] is not a valid device pointer. Can you edit you question to explain where B is allocated, and what CUDA version you are using?

Comment: Which is the host pointer array and device pointer array among A and B? Have you allocated device memories for all the P pointers in the device pointer array using cudaMalloc?

Comment: I've addded host side code above,d_a is device pointer.So basically i'm allocating 1D array on GPU and using it as 2D array by typecasting it

Comment: @user997704: that isn't very helpful. Can you show where the pointers are defined and allocated?

Comment: @user997704: Your `cudaMalloc` call is probably wrong. Can you confirm that is the code you are really using?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `d_a` isn't a valid device pointer, because your `cudaMalloc` call looks to be incorrect. It should be something like this:

```
int *d_a;
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_a,P*P*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: @user997704: Trust me, it does make a very big difference.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it?I'm curious to know...may some example or theory will do...

Comment: [This answer to a C programming question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838038/c-programming-malloc-inside-another-function) explains what is wrong with your call to cudaMalloc (it is equivalent to calling malloc inside another function).