# bad output in printing even/odd numbers in array - c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

I have an array of numbers ..
what is needed : to create 2 new arrays by malloc 
one for even numbers and one for odd numbers 
and we need to print them in main with the size of each array too

**Array is 1,2,5,6,8,4,5,10,65,69,98,76,46,49,67**

**Even Array must be: 2,6,8,4,10,98,76,46**

**Odd Array must be: 1,5,5,65,69,49,67**

**The function must be written like this (this is how the teacher wants)**

```
void evenodd(int a[],int** even,int* evensize,int** odd,int* oddsize)
```

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 15
void evenodd(int a[],int** even,int* evensize,int** odd,int* oddsize)
{
    int i,j,cnte,cnto,e,o;
    cnte=cnto=0;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    if(a[i]%2==0) cnte++;
    else cnto++;

    even=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*cnte);
    *evensize=cnte;
    odd=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*cnto);
    *oddsize=cnto;

    for(i=0,o=0,e=0;i<N;i++)
        if(a[i]%2==0)
        even[e++]=a[i];
        else odd[o++]=a[i];
  return;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    int a[N]={1,2,5,6,8,4,5,10,65,69,98,76,46,49,67};
int *even,evensize,*odd,oddsize;
evenodd(a,&even,&evensize,&odd,&oddsize);
printf("Even Numbers Array: ");
for(i=0;i<evensize;i++)
printf("%d ",even[i]);
printf("\nSize of even array is: %d",evensize);
    printf("\n\n");
printf("Even Numbers Array: ");
for(i=0;i<oddsize;i++)
    printf("%d ",odd[i]);
printf("\nSize of even array is: %d",oddsize);
}
```

i think the error is in Malloc .. but i dont know why ..

Comment: `*even=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*cnte);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Nope, `*even = malloc(sizeof(int) * cnte);`.

Comment: homework tag, anyone?

Comment: @PhilipConrad Well, where you have been since this spring? :) The `homework` tag is deprecated.

Comment: @H2CO3 Whoops! My bad. I haven't been on SO recently, so I probably missed that announcement.

Comment: @PhilipConrad Yeah, it wasn't too long time ago. The SO staff argued that it's not useful, so it should not be used anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since C function calls use pass by value, to pass back a value through an out parameter, you need a pointer to the variable that will hold the value being passed back. But, within that function, you need to dereference the pointer to change the value stored in the variable so that the caller sees the value being passed back. (You get this right for your counter function parameters, `evensize` and `oddsize`.)

To take an example, your `even` array is being assigned like this:

```
    even=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*cnte);
```

When you dynamically allocate an item (or in this case an array of items) of type `FOO`, `malloc()` logically returns a `FOO *`. *You should **not** cast the return value of* `malloc()`, but your cast is wrong anyway, it should have been:

```
    even=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*cnte);
```

However, `even` is an `int **`, which is a pointer to the `int *even` variable in `main()`. To let `main()` see the result, you have to dereference the pointer passed to your function. As mentioned previously, you should not cast the result of `malloc()`, as it can mask an error if its prototype is missing, which can lead to undefined behavior in the worst case.

```
    *even=malloc(sizeof(int)*cnte);
```

In C, the declaration of the variable mimics use. So `int **even` means that `**even` is an `int`. So, to assign an `int` value properly, `even` has to be dereferenced twice. The first time to get to the array allocated by `malloc()`, and a second time to reach the desired index position. So, your assignment statement:

```
        even[e++]=a[i];
```

is wrong because it is assigning an `int` value to an `int *` type since `even` is only dereferenced once. Since `even` is a pointer to an `int *`, use:

```
        (*even)[e++] = a[i];
```

Similarly, make the same corrections for the `odd` function parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Update allocation as

```
*even = malloc(sizeof(int)*cnte);
*odd = malloc(sizeof(int)*cnto);
```

and use as

```
for(i=0,o=0,e=0;i<N;i++)
    if(a[i]%2==0)
      (*even)[e++]=a[i];
    else 
      (*odd)[o++]=a[i];
```

Comment: +1, would be useful to insert a link to the standard "don't cast malloc" answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your `malloc` calls are:

```
even=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*cnte);
...
odd=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*cnto);
```

Your first clue that this is wrong should be that `even` and `odd` are *output* parameters to your `evenodd` function, but here you're modifying *local variables*.  C passes arguments by value; in order to modify objects passed by the caller, you must add a level indirection (a pointer). (See my answer to [C Programming: malloc() inside another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838038/c-programming-malloc-inside-another-function/2838207#2838207) for an explanation about this.)

Therefore the `malloc` calls should be:

```
*even=malloc(sizeof(int)*cnte);
...
*odd=malloc(sizeof(int)*cnto);
```

Note that in C, it is unnecessary to explicitly cast the result of `malloc` (and [doing so can hide errors](http://www.c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html)).  It's also generally recommended to use `p = malloc(sizeof *p)` instead of `p = malloc(sizeof (type))` so that if the type of `p` changes, you don't silently allocate an incorrect buffer size:

```
*even=malloc(sizeof **even * cnte);
...
*odd=malloc(sizeof **odd * cnto);
```