# How to initialize and allocate a char** argument inside a function

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, arguments

I have a `readfile` function called by `main`. The criteria is I have to pass `char**` into `readfile`, and I have to allocate and initialize this argument inside `readfile`. I am a bit confused about how to deal with `char**` in a subfunction.

```
void main()
{
      char** data;
      readfile(data);
}

void readfile(char** data)
{
   data = (char**)malloc(1000);   //give me Segmentation fault
   data = (char*)malloc(1000); //give me " warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type" during compliation.
   data = (char)malloc(1000); //give me "warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size" during compilation.

}
```

I tried to cast a pointer to it first e.g. `char* pdata = *data;`
and I can use `pdata` ok.

How can I allocate this variable inside the `readfile` function?

Comment: We have no idea what your `readfile` want to do. Your code does not read any file!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838038/c-programming-malloc-inside-another-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions:

1. Allocate memory in main
2. Pass the address of the pointer like this:

   ```
   void main()
   {
       char** data;
       readfile(&data); //notice the pass of data adress to the function
   }

   void readfile(char*** data)  //notice the extra * operator added
   {
       *data = malloc(1000); 
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The requirement is to use char** as a param and allocate the memory inside the function. And I have to be able to bring the array back to main.

Comment: Yeah that's very cute, but it can't be done if you need to pass a pointer to a pointer. If you have a pointer to a pointer you parameter has to be char*** data.

Comment: Thanks. I will allocate memory in main then. I can just do char* data instead. And it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want `char*data=NULL;` in `main` then call `readfile(&data);` there. Any  change to formal argument `data` inside `readfile` is not propagated to the caller (because C has a [call by value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy) semantics when passing arguments).

Also, you should *always* test the result of  `malloc` like e.g.

```
data = malloc(1000);
if (!data) { perror("malloc data"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

and you probably should initialize the obtained memory zone, perhaps using

```
memset (data, 0, 1000);
```

or simply use `calloc` to get zeroed memory.

If you pass `&data` from `main` declare your formal argument of `readfile` as `char**ptr` and do inside `readfile` something like `*ptr = malloc(1000);` etc...

BTW, did you consider using [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)? It probably is relevant.