# Allocating memory for a pointer inside a function call in C

Tags: c

I've made an example program to illustrate the problem. In `test` I allocate memory for `foo` to store two integers. Then, I set each of these integers to a value, and then I print them. Pretty simple, except I can only assign values to the integers if I do it inside of `main` - it won't work when I do it inside of `test`.

---

This code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void test(int **foo) {
    *foo = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
}

int main() {
    int *foo;

    test(&foo);

    foo[0] = 4;  // <---
    foo[1] = 3;  // <---

    printf("foo[0]: %d\n", foo[0]);
    printf("foo[1]: %d\n", foo[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
foo[0]: 4
foo[1]: 3
```

---

This code doesn't:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void test(int **foo) {
    *foo = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));  // 3.
    *foo[0] = 4;  // 4. <---
    *foo[1] = 3;  // 5. <---
}

int main() {
    int *foo;  // 1.

    test(&foo);  // 2.

    printf("foo[0]: %d\n", foo[0]);
    printf("foo[1]: %d\n", foo[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
foo[0]: 4        // This is only 4 because it was already
                 //   4 from running the previous example
foo[1]: 5308612  // And this is obviously garbage
```

---

So, what's going on? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2838207/1883424) has been very helpful (or I thought it was at least), but it doesn't address why the assignments work in `main` but not `test`.

Here's my understanding of how the code in the second example should be working (I've put footnotes in the code to indicate the lines I'm referring to here):

1. The program starts at `main`. I create the integer point `foo`, which is assigned a 4-byte block of memory at (for the sake of simplicity) address `1000`.
2. I send a reference to `foo` to the function `test`. So, it is passed `1000` as its parameter.
3. A block of memory two integers in size (8 bytes) is allocated for `foo`.
4. `4` is stored at address `1000`
5. `3` is stored at address `1004`

So, what am I misunderstanding, and how can I fix the code in the second example so I can do my initialization of `foo` in a `test` rather than `main`?

Thanks!

Comment: +1: Nice job on the SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — it makes it so much easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks! I've learned my lesson about rushing the questions in the past.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Precedence!

You need:

```
(*foo)[0] = 4;  // 4. <---
(*foo)[1] = 3;  // 5. <---
```

Without the parentheses, `*foo[0]` is `*(foo[0])`, which is actually the same as `(*foo)[0]`, but
`*(foo[1])` goes writing who-knows-where.  The `*` operator binds less tightly than the `[]` operator does, so you have to use parentheses.

```
char *arr[];   // array of pointers to char
char (*arr)[]; // pointer to array of char
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the problem. I hadn't even considered precedence; I was too hung up on dereferencing. I got it working in the more complicated program, too. Glad that was the only issue.

Answer (score 3):

try this and you will see...order of operations:

```
void test(int **foo) {
    *foo = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));  // 3.
    (*foo)[0] = 4;  // 4. <---
    (*foo)[1] = 3;  // 5. <---
}
```

foo is a pointer to an int pointer. Accessing foo[1] would access whatever is on the stack after the foo declaration in main (nothing, so bad memory). You need to dereference before using the array [] operator. Hence, the parens should fix it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the problem. I hadn't even considered precedence; I was too hung up on dereferencing. I got it working in the more complicated program, too. Glad that was the only issue.

Answer (score 0):

Like Jonathan pointed out, it's a problem with operator precedence. `[]` has precedence over `*`, so it was being processed as an *array of int pointers* rather than a *pointer to an array of ints*.

Another possible solution that would avoid using pointers to pointers entirely would be for the function `test()` to return the memory address with the allocated memory instead of receiving `foo` as an argument.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* test() {
    int *bar = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    bar[0] = 4;
    bar[1] = 3;

    return bar;
}

int main() {
    int *foo = test();

    printf("foo[0]: %d\n", foo[0]);
    printf("foo[1]: %d\n", foo[1]);

    free(foo);
    return 0;
}
```