# What I'm doing wrong with this structure?

Tags: c++, struct

So, I'm making a structure that works with videos that is supposed to import them from a txt file and I get an error on line 42(uninitialized local variable filme use) and I don't know how to fix it. I can't change `Main` function.

Any help please ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

struct Filme {
public:
    //string name;
    int anu;
    string denumire;
    //int ani;
    //vector<string>den;

    
};
void Import(int n, Filme* film,string den) {
    
    ifstream ifs(den);
    string denumire;
    int anu;
    while (!ifs.eof()) {
        ifs >> denumire >> anu;
        film->denumire = denumire;
        film->anu = anu;
    }
}
void Afisare(Filme *filme)
{
    cout << filme->denumire<< endl;
    cout << filme->anu << endl;
}
int main()
{
    Filme* filme;
    int n;
    cout << "Cate filme doriti sa importati din fisier: ";
    cin >> n;
    Import(n, filme, "filme.txt");
    //Sort(filme);
    Afisare(filme);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you create a new filme variable `Filme* filme` but never assign any value to it.

Comment: are you aware that *** line 42*** is telling us nothing???

Comment: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Answer (score 1):

you should not do this

```
film->denumire = denumire;
```

in

```
void Import(int n, Filme* film,string den) {
```

because film is a non initialized pointer you created in main...

```
Filme* filme;
....
Import(n, filme, "filme.txt");
```

you have to init it properly

```
Filme* filme = new Filme...
```

Comment: Can I fix it without changing `Main` ? I'm supposed to make it work without changing it

Answer (score 0):

You just define a pointer. Where is its memory allocation?! ;)

```
Filme* filme = new Filme();
```

pay attention to delete the pointer at the end.

```
delete filme;
filme = nullptr; //for c++11
```

Comment: I can't change `Main` function, any way to fix it without changing it ?

Comment: You can do what @YvonneY says in his post If you can modify the Import function.

Answer (score 0):

You may refers to the topic
[C++ how to pass an uninitialized pointer to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690526/c-how-to-pass-an-uninitialized-pointer-to-a-function)

```
void Import(int n, Filme* &film, string den) {

    ifstream ifs(den);
    string denumire;
    int anu;
    while (!ifs.eof()) {
        ifs >> denumire >> anu;
        film = new Filme();
        film->denumire = denumire;
        film->anu = anu;
    }
}
```