# C pass (double)pointer as reference / parameter with malloc

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, parameter-passing, double-pointer

I want to pass a variable by parameter and then allocated a memory region using malloc to that parameter. Actually, I know how to do that, but I was wondering `why` this function does not work as I expected:

```
void temp1(int *a) {
    int *b = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    a = b; // a receives the pointer from b, only while it's in temp1 function;
}
```

while this function works:

```
void temp2(int **a) {
    int *b = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *a = b;
}
```

when calling this way from main:

```
int main()
    int *t1 = NULL;
    temp1(t1); // but after exiting the temp1 function the t1 value is still NULL

    int *t2;
    temp2(&t2); // this works 

    return 0;
}
```

So, what I'm missing in the function `temp1` that avoids it to work? Is it because in function `temp1` I'm trying to change the content of the parameter `int *a`? I mean, when I do `a = b;` in `temp1` the `a` holds only a copy of the address that I wanted to assign to `t1`?

Comment: `a = b;` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: `temp1` clobbers its *local* value of `a`.  This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2838207/179715