# Cant pass a correct Dynamic array of structs in c

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct, calloc

Im working on a project for school and I can't pass a dynamic array of structs to another function in c. The function is just supposed to check an element of the struct and return alreadyadded if that element of the array is equal to the current one. Im also having trouble declaring the function that accepts the calloc array. Any help would be appreciated! Ive been looking for a solution for this all night.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
struct EDGETAG;
typedef struct
     {
      char c;
      bool isVisited;
      struct EDGETAG* p;
     } VERTEX;

typedef struct EDGE
    {
    VERTEX* v;
    struct EDGETAG* q;
    } EDGE;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   {
    int a;
    struct VERTEX *vert = (VERTEX*)calloc(100, sizeof (VERTEX*));
    char s;
    int count = 0;
    FILE* input = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    while((a = fgetc(input)) != EOF)
       {
        if(isspace(a)==0)
         {
         s = a;
         printf("%c ",s);
         determiner(s,vert,count);
         count++;            
         }
      }
return 0;
}
```

and the called function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


typedef struct VERTEX
    {
    char c;
    bool isVisited;
    struct EDGETAG* p;
    } VERTEX;


typedef struct EDGETAG
    {
   VERTEX* v;
    struct EDGETAG* q;
    } EDGE;


void determiner (char a, struct VERTEX *vert, int count)
    {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i < count; i++)
       {
       if(vert[i].c == a)
         {
         printf("%c allready added ",vert[i].c);
         return ;
         }
     else
       {
       VERTEX* new1 = (VERTEX*)malloc(sizeof(VERTEX));
       new1->c = a;
       vert[i] = *new1;
      }
    }
return ;
```

input is:
A  B
B  C
E  X
C  D
A  C 
output:A B B B allreadyadded C E X C D A C

Comment: `I can't pass a dynamic array` what's the issue?

Comment: you should return a bool from `determiner` to indicate if the element was found or newly allocated, and only in the latter case should `count` be increased, otherwise you access unintialized memory

Comment: Did you want to make a linked list of vertices? Are you sure they should be in an array?

Comment: Why aren't the type definitions in a header?  They should be.  DRY — Don't Repeat Yourself.  And please learn to indent your code in an orthodox manner.  It dramatically improves the chances of people being able to spot your problem.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Please indent your code correctly.

Comment: I'm trying to make an array of vertices.

Comment: @wawiiii: but there is a difference between an array of vertices, and an array of pointers to vertices. With the former, you instantiate space for holding actual data, while with the latter you only instantiate space for holding pointers and you need to allocate each VERTEX separately. A pointer to an array of pointers should be `VERTEX**`, not `VERTEX*`, **or** you simply need to allocate the former (simpler) array with `sizeof(VERTEX)` in the main body. And then your `determiner` function (which is incorrect like explained below) doesn't need to allocate anything, just change `count`.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838038/c-programming-malloc-inside-another-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never actually allocate any vertexes.

```
struct VERTEX *vert = (VERTEX*)calloc(100, sizeof (VERTEX*));
```

Notice the `sizeof(VERTEX*)`? You've allocated enough space for 100 pointers to vertexes!

Comment: Doesn't this allocate space for 100 *vertices* (not pointers to vertices)? Also, it's `sizeof(VERTEX)` in OP's code.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Notice the `sizeof (VERTEX*)`?

Comment: I was presuming this was a typo, since it's `sizeof(VERTEX)` inside the function. Additionally, I would expect a pointer to an array of pointers to be `struct VERTEX **`? This way `*vert` just takes a couple of `int` pointers and cast them to a `VERTEX`.

Comment: It may well be a typo, but that doesn't make it any less disastrous.

Comment: @Groo I think David is talking about the call in `main()`, that's the problematic one.

Comment: @Sourav: yes, my mistake, I saw the bottom part of the question along with David's answer, David is obviously correct.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the issue David Schwartz pointed out, an indented version of `determiner` shows another problem more clearly:

```
void determiner(char a, struct VERTEX *vert, int count)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (vert[i].c == a)
        {
            printf("%c allready added ", vert[i].c);
            return;
        }
        else{
            VERTEX* new1 = (VERTEX*)malloc(sizeof(VERTEX));
            new1->c = a;
            vert[i] = *new1;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Your current code looks at the first element of the array to see if it matches with `a`

- If it does match, it returns (good)
- If it doesn't match it overwrites the first element with new data (bad)

It then loops and does the same thing with the second element etc.

To fix this, move the code that adds a new element outside of the checking loop. If the checking loop finishes, then it hasn't been found, so can then be added.

Now, you have a second problem - you always increase `count` no matter whether `determiner` found a match or not. You should change `determiner` to return a value indicating whether the item was added, then use that in `main` to increase count or not.

Edit: Also note - you don't need (or want) to allocate the new node using malloc, if you are just going to copy its contents into `vert[i]`. Currently you are leaking memory - much easier to just update `vert[i].c` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling in the first file

```
typedef struct
{
  char c;
  bool isVisited;
  struct EDGETAG* p;
} VERTEX;
```

Later down, you have

```
struct VERTEX *vert = ...
```

`struct VERTEX` is not a type in the first file. `VERTEX` is defined as a type. You should change the struct type to

```
typedef struct VERTEX // note the VERTEX here
{
  char c;
  bool isVisited;
  struct EDGETAG* p;
} VERTEX;
```

This is already done in the second file.

As a general style guide, you should include the struct declarations for `VERTEX` and `EDGE` in a separate header file and include it in both your `.c` files.

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with your code, but I will add my 2 cents to the answers above, since I believe it might be helpful:

1. As @David already noticed, you are instantiating an array of pointers:

   ```
   // this should be a struct VERTEX**, if you want to
   // have a "pointer to the first pointer to VERTEX"
   struct VERTEX *vert = (VERTEX*)calloc(100, sizeof (VERTEX*));
   ```

   but you (most likely) wanted to instantiate an array of VERTEXes:

   ```
   // you probably want space for 100 x sizeof(VERTEX),
   // so that vert is simply a "pointer to the first VERTEX".
   // ALSO: don't cast the result of calloc/malloc 
   struct VERTEX *vert = calloc(100, sizeof(VERTEX));
   ```

   `vert` is not a pointer to the first `VERTEX` element of the allocated array. You don't need to allocate individual `VERTEX` elements and `vert` is never going to be `null` as you iterate, so you need to keep track of the `count` yourself.
2. `count` shouldn't be incremented inside the `main` body, since you don't know if you actually added the element or not.
3. Your `determiner` function is not correct; you seem to be adding a new instance in **each** loop iteration. I would also return the count value from the function when it actually adds the element:

   ```
   void determiner (char a, struct VERTEX *vert, int *count)
   {
       for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
       {
           if (vert[i].c == a)
           {
               printf("%c already added ",vert[i].c);

               // no need to increase count
               return;
           }
       }

       // if we are here, we didn't find the element,
       // so this is where you actually initialize it
       // and increase count

       vert[count]->c = a;
       count++;
   }
   ```

   When calling the function, pass the pointer to `count` and let the function increase it:

   ```
   determiner(s, vert, &count);
   ```
4. When working with graphs, it's common to use a linked list, i.e. make nodes point to other nodes. In that case you don't allocate an array, but use `malloc` for each node separately and jump forward until you reach `null`. Try googling for an example of how to implement a graph in C to get a better idea of the proper approach.