# Dynamic memory allocation mismatch

Tags: c, memory, malloc, structure

I'm stuck with memory allocation for a couple of hours now. Basically, I have to add a new Graphic Element to the Vector Graphic for which initialization of `VectorGraphic` is necessary.

First problem is with memory allocation inside the `InitVectorGraphic` method which is fixed? (I think) Now the second problem I'm stuck with is that even though memory is allocated from `InitVectorGraphic` method, `pElements` has no memory inside the `AddGraphicElement` method. (i.e, even after initializing it in one method (`InitVectorGraphic` method), changes won't reflect in other methods)

Here is my full code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

enum{ 
    RUNNING = 1 
}; 

struct Point        
{
    int x, y; 
}; 

struct Line        
{ 
    Point start; 
    Point end; 
}; 

struct GraphicElement     
{ 
    enum{ 
        SIZE = 256 
    }; 
    unsigned int numLines;
    Line* pLines; 
    char name[SIZE]; 
}; 

typedef struct         
{ 
    unsigned int numGraphicElements; 
    GraphicElement* pElements; 
}VectorGraphic; 

void InitVectorGraphic(VectorGraphic* image){
    image = (VectorGraphic*)malloc(sizeof(VectorGraphic));
    (*image).pElements = (GraphicElement*)malloc(sizeof(GraphicElement)* 256);
//Problem part 1
    };

void AddGraphicElement(VectorGraphic* image){
    printf("\nADDING A Graphic Element"); //Problem part 2
    int index = (*image).numGraphicElements;

    printf("\nPlease enter the name of the new GraphicElement(<256 characters): ");
    scanf("%s", &(*image).pElements[index].name);
    printf("How many lines are there in the  new GraphicElement? ");
    scanf("%d", &(*image).pElements[index].numLines);
    (*image).pElements[index].pLines = (Line*)malloc(sizeof(Line)* (*image).pElements[index].numLines);
    for (int i = 0; i < (*image).pElements[index].numLines; i++){
        Line line;
        printf("Please enter the x coord of the start point of line index %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &line.start.x);
        printf("Please enter the y coord of the start point of line index  %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &line.start.y);
        printf("Please enter the x coord of the end point of line index %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &line.end.x);
        printf("Please enter the y coord of the end point of line index %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &line.end.y);

        (*image).pElements[index].pLines[i] = line;
    }

    (*image).numGraphicElements = (*image).numGraphicElements + 1;
    printf("Added");
    //add graphicElement to Image

};
void ReportVectorGraphic(VectorGraphic* image){
    printf("\nVectorGraphic Report");
    for (int i = 0; i < (*image).numGraphicElements; i++){
        printf("\nReporting Graphic Element #%d", i);
        printf("\nGraphic Element name: %s", (*image).pElements[i].name);
        for (int j = 0; j < (*image).pElements[i].numLines; j++){
            printf("\nLine #%d start x: %d", j, (*image).pElements[i].pLines[j].start.x);
            printf("\nLine #%d start y: %d", j, (*image).pElements[i].pLines[j].start.y);
            printf("\nLine #%d end x: %d", j, (*image).pElements[i].pLines[j].end.x);
            printf("\nLine #%d end y: %d", j, (*image).pElements[i].pLines[j].end.y);
        }       
    }

};

void CleanUpVectorGraphic(VectorGraphic* image){
    free(image);
};

VectorGraphic Image; 


int main()        
{ 
    char response; 
    InitVectorGraphic(&Image); 
    while (RUNNING)               
    { 
        printf("\nPlease select an option:\n");
        printf("1. Add a Graphic Element\n"); 
        printf("2. List the Graphic Elements\n"); 
        printf("q. Quit\n"); printf("CHOICE: ");
        fflush(stdin); 
        scanf("%c", &response); 
        switch (response)                      
        { 
        case '1':AddGraphicElement(&Image); 
            break; 
        case '2':ReportVectorGraphic(&Image);
            break; 
        case 'q':CleanUpVectorGraphic(&Image); 
            return 0;
        default:printf("Please enter a valid option\n"); 
        }
        printf("\n"); 
    } 
}
```

What is the solution?

Comment: Is this c or c++?

Comment: When I define `void f(int x) {x = 5;}` and then do `int i = 7; f(i);` what is the value of i afterwards? What about if I do `f(7);` - what is the value of 7 afterwards? And finally, if I define `void g(int *q) {q = malloc(sizeof(int));}` and do `int *p = NULL; g(p);` what is the value of p afterwards?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is in C. @CaptainGiraffe

Comment: Have you worked through with a debugger? First look shows various problems, such as with `scanf` and not realising that a function takes a *copy* of the variable you supply and then forgets it on return. In `InitVectorGraphic` you immediately overwrite the pointer argument supplied and after its return there will be a memory leak.

Comment: 1) Don't spam language tags! 2) C does not support _methods_, only _functions_. 3) Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is not defined by the C language - remove it, or update your tags to indicate which language you are really using.

Comment: `#include<conio.h>` is not defined by the C language - remove it, or update your tags to indicate which language you are really using.

Comment: Read about "pass by value". It's always a mistake to take a function parameter and then overwrite the old value of the parameter on the first line of the function.

Comment: My answer to [C Programming: malloc() inside another function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2838207/179715) might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

This is very standard confusion with pointers. You need following changes:

```
VectorGraphic* Image; //make it a pointer
void InitVectorGraphic(VectorGraphic** image) //expect pointer-to-pointer
{
    *image = (VectorGraphic*)malloc(sizeof(VectorGraphic)); //assign allocated buffer to pointer
    (*image)->pElements = (GraphicElement*)malloc(sizeof(GraphicElement)* 256);
}

InitVectorGraphic(&Image); //call remains the same
```

In your old code, you are leaking memory, you can think of image as local defined variable as below:

```
InitVectorGraphic(VectorGraphic* image)
{
  image = malloc(); //Here you are allocating memory to a local variable not to the address Image
  //no free()'ing of image variable
}
```

Steps of execution as per your old code are simply making two assignment with second assignment overwriting original one:

```
VectorGraphic *image = &Image;
image = malloc();
```