# Passing pointer to a function and allocating space inside called function. Possible in C?

Tags: c

I have a requirement to pass some sort of reference pointer (not allocating space for it yet in calling function). I want malloc call in called function. There could be any number of objects present and pointed to by the pointer (like `(pointer+index)=malloc(..)`) to allocate space in called function. And also in the calling function I need the ability to access and modify objects like `(pointer+index)->member=some_val` or `pointer[index]->member=some_val`. Is this possible?

This is what I tried:

```
struct abc{ char *c;};

void abc(struct abc *t);
void main() {
    struct abc *k;
    printf("%s",k->c);
}
void abc(struct abc *t){
    t=(struct abc *)malloc(sizeof(struct abc));
    *t->c="hello";
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing address contained by pointer using function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431108/changing-address-contained-by-pointer-using-function)

Comment: Or this? [C Programming: malloc() inside another function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2838038/)

Comment: I  think that is what you are asking though it isn't entirely clear. You can pass in a `struct abc **t_p` and then return the allocated memory to the caller as such: `*t_p = malloc(..);`. In the caller it would be `struct abc *k; abc(&k);`

Comment: @jamesdlin this line in called function in my example is not compiling `t->c="hello";` How can I access in both called and calling function members of objects pointed to by pointer reference?

Comment: @kaylum same as above comment

Comment: `(*t_p)->c = "hello";` Note: you have to change the function paramter to `abc **t_p` if you want the caller to be able to get a reference to the allocated memory, That is, you need to pass in a pointer to the pointer.

Comment: @kaylum thanks, few words of explanation may be?

Comment: @kaylum what if I keep the parameter same but assign the parameter passed pointer to `struct abc **t_p=&parameter_pointer` will it work?

Comment: When you pass a pointer to a function, the function receives a copy of the pointer. You are allocating and assigning the result to a copy of the original pointer. Change to `void abc(struct abc **t)` and call with `*t=malloc(sizeof **t);` and `(*t)->c = "hello";` Or just declare `struct abc *abc (void) { struct abc * t = malloc (sizeof *t); t->c = "hello"; return t; }` and assign `struct abc *k = abc();` in main. Note you need to validate the return of `malloc()` each time and you do not need to cast the return of `malloc()` in C (you do in C++).

Comment: In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) Also, since you are assigning the address of a string-literal to `c`, you cannot modify the contents of the memory pointed to by `c`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `Also, since you are assigning the address of a string-literal to c, you cannot modify the contents of the memory pointed to by c` what this mean but I am able to modify it, I checked in main tried `k->c=some_val` it worked

Comment: A Sting-Literal, e.g. `"hello"` is non-mutable. For most executable types, string literals are place in the `.rodata` section of the executable (read-only data). So if you attempt `t->c[0] = 'j';` attempting to change `"hello"` to `"jello"` you will most likely SegFault. (there are non-standard compilers that allow modification of string literals... but note the **non-** part)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin so you are saying if I plan to change the value of `c` (initially assiged string literal) the segfault can occur. if yes then how exactly I assign some string like `hello` in abc and change it to `jello` in main or abc

Comment: Yes, you can change where the pointer points (e.g. `t->c = "new hello";`), but you cannot change the content of the string literal itself. (e.g. `t->c[1] = 'o';` attempting to change `"new"` to `"now"` -- BOOM SegFault) If you want `c` mutable, you need to allocate storage for it, e.g. `t->c = malloc (strlen ("hello") + 1);` and then copy `strcpy (t->c, "hello");` Now you have a mutable copy of the string-literal you can freely modify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing from the comments, your initial problem is you are passing a pointer *by-value* to your function `abc()`. The function will receive a copy of the pointer and any changes you make to the copy of the pointer in function `abc()` will be lost when the function returns. (you also incorrectly dereference `*t->c = "hello";`)

You have two optons:

**Pass the Address Of the Pointer**

When you pass the address of the pointer to your function, you will pass a *pointer-to-pointer* holding the original address of your pointer from `main()` to your function. You can then change the address held by the original pointer by updating the address held by the original pointer in your `abc()` function. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct abc {
    char *c;
};

void abc (struct abc **t)           /* use pointer-to-poitner to struct abc */
{
    *t = malloc (sizeof **t);       /* allocate */
    
    if (*t == NULL) {               /* validate */
        perror ("malloc-*t");
        return;
    }
    
    (*t)->c = "hello";              /* assign on success */
}

int main (void) {       /* void main only valid in freestanding environment */
    
    struct abc *k;
    
    abc (&k);                       /* call abc passing address of k */
    
    if (k) {                        /* validate k not NULL */
        puts (k->c);
        free (k);                   /* don't forget to free what you allocate */
    }
}
```

(**note:** you must ***validate*** EVERY allocation by ***checking the return*** from `malloc()` is not `NULL`)

Also note the use of the derefernced pointer to set the *type-size* for the allocation. If you always use the dereferenced pointer to set the type-size, you will never get it wrong. In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714).

The parenthesis around `(*t)->c = "hello";` are necessary for C-operator precedence. If you omit them (e.g. `*t->c`), you will receive an error because `t` (holding the address of the original pointer) is not type `struct abc*`, but instead is type `struct abc**` and as such has no member named `c`.

**Exmaple Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/abc_ptr2ptr
hello
```

**Change The Function Return Type to `struct abc *` And Return Allocated Pointer**

Your second option is simply to change the return type of your `abc()` function to return a pointer to `struct abc` (e.g. `struct abc*`). Making that change you do not need to pass any parameter to your function. You can simply declare the pointer local to your function and allocate storage for one `struct abc` assigning the address of the allocated block to your local pointer and then return that pointer to the caller (`main()` here)

For example, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct abc {
    char *c;
};

struct abc *abc (void)                      /* return pointer to allocated struct */
{
    struct abc *t = malloc (sizeof *t);     /* allocate */
    
    if (t == NULL) {                        /* validate */
        perror ("malloc-t");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    t->c = "hello";                         /* assign on success */
    
    return t;                               /* return pointer to allocated struct */
}

int main (void) {       /* void main only valid in freestanding environment */
    
    struct abc *k = abc();                  /* declare and initialize k */
    
    if (k) {                                /* validate k not NULL */
        puts (k->c);
        free (k);                           /* don't forget to free what you allocate */
    }
}
```

Don't forget to validate the return...

(the output is the same)

**Proper Declaration for `main()` is `int main()` Unless in a Freestanding Environment**

Unless you are programming in a *freestanding environment* (without the benefit of any OS), in a standards conforming implementation, the allowable declarations for `main` for are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char **argv`).  See: [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup(p1)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). See also: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

In a freestanding environment, the name and type of the function called at program startup are implementation-defined. See: [C11 Standard - 5.1.2.1 Freestanding environment](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.1)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.