# Creating a buffer inside a function and assigniing values to its elements in C

Tags: c, function, buffer

I have a new question that is related to my posting at the link [Allocating dynamic memory in C in a functio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72035757/allocating-dynamic-memory-in-c-in-a-functio?noredirect=1#comment127290674_72035757) for creating a uniform BMP image with specified colors for some tests. As before I'm using Visual Studio 2022 on a Windows 10 platform.

In the main function I have the following code:

```
int numCheckBytes;
BYTE* bufPix = NULL;
CINT numPixBytes = createImgPix(width, height, red, green, blue, &numCheckBytes, &bufPix);
```

where the width and height in pixels are specified, red, green and blue are bytes with values between 0 and 255, numCheckBytes is a returned value, and bufPix is a buffer declared as NULL before the function is called.

Inside the function createImgPix() I have the following code:

```
CINT createImgPix(int width, int height, CBYTE rd, CBYTE gn, CBYTE bl, int* countChk, BYTE** buf) {
  if (*buf != NULL) return -1; // Buffer already has something in it.
  CBYTE color[] = { bl, gn, rd }; // A BMP image has the colors in reverse order, i.e. as blue, green and red.
  int pixVer = 0;
  int pixByte = 0;
  int byteCount = 0;
  CINT padding = (4 - ((width * 3) % 4)) % 4; // Number of padding bytes at the end of each row.
  CINT pixByteRow = width * 3; // Number of pixels bytes in a row.
  CINT rowBufLen = pixByteRow + padding; // Total number of bytes in a row including any padding.
  CINT bufLen = rowBufLen * height; // Total number of bytes including any padding.
  int offset = 0;

  // Allocate a buffer to hold all the pixel data.
  *buf = (BYTE*)malloc(bufLen);
  if (*buf == NULL) return -2; // Failed to allocate memory.

  for (pixVer = 0; pixVer < height; pixVer++) { // Loop over rows.

      for (pixByte = 0; pixByte < pixByteRow; pixByte++) { // Loop over pixels in a row.
          *(buf + pixByte) = color[pixByte % 3]; // <== (1)
          byteCount++;
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < padding; i++) { // Add any padding bytes.
          pixByte = 3 * width + i;
          *(buf + pixByte) = 0; // <== (2)
          byteCount;
      }

      offset += rowBufLen; // Increment offset by number of bytes in a row.
  }

  *countChk = byteCount - 3 * width * height - height * padding;    // Check total bytes counted against image size.
  return byteCount;
}
```

The idea is to allocate the buffer inside the function, populate it with values, then return the buffer with its populated values to the main function. When compiling the application I get the warning message for (1) as "warning C4047: '=': 'BYTE *' differs in levels of indirection from 'CBYTE'". I get no warning for (2), but presumably there is a similar problem. Note that in the header I have:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
typedef const unsigned char CBYTE;
```

If for (1) I have instead the statement:

```
*buf[pixByte] = color[pixByte % 3];
```

the program compiles correctly but an exception is thrown at that line when the code is executed.

In an earlier version of this function I created a temporary buffer inside it with the line:

```
buf = malloc(rowBufLen);
```

and line (1) was instead:

```
buf[pixByte] = color[pixByte % 3];
```

which worked correctly. In that case I wrote to a buffer for each line scanned, copied the buffer to a file, then reused the buffer for the next lines, etc. discarding it when returning from the function, with the image written to a file. Now I want the pixel part of the image kept in a buffer, which can be accessed from main.

Getting some help with this would be most appreciated. Incidentally, I always document my code with comments, but they don't come out well here.

Comment: Don't comment your code to say *what* it does, describe *why* it does something.

Comment: `if (*buf == NULL)` No, you dont.

Answer (score 0):

At this line:

```
*(buf + pixByte) = color[pixByte % 3];
```

You have `buf` which is a `BYTE**` and (presumably) contains the address of a variable defined in the calling function.  When you add `pixByte` to this, you're actually offsetting the address of that variable instead of indexing the memory block that was returned.

This is close:

```
*buf[pixByte] = color[pixByte % 3];
```

But the array index operator has higher precedence than the dereference operator.  What you actually want is:

```
(*buf)[pixByte] = color[pixByte % 3];
```

The other line has the same problem.  The reason you don't get an error is because `0` is a valid null pointer constant.

Answer (score 0):

OK, many thanks, I got this to work. It's one of the nuances of C that I missed. I forgot to account for the offset, so the relevant part of the code is now:

```
//...
int offset = 0;

// Allocate a buffer to hold all the pixel data.
*buf = (BYTE*)malloc(bufLen);
if (*buf == NULL) return -2;

for (pixVer = 0; pixVer < height; pixVer++) {

    for (pixByte = 0; pixByte < pixByteRow; pixByte++) {
        (*buf)[pixByte + offset] = color[pixByte % 3]; // <== (1)
        byteCount++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < padding; i++) {
        pixByte = 3 * width + i;
        (*buf)[pixByte + offset] = 0; // <== (2)
        byteCount;
    }

    offset += rowBufLen;
}
//...
```

with (1) and (2) changed with the offset included. Now indeed I do get a uniformly colored image when combined with the header and written to a file.

However, the IDE shows (1) underlined in green with the following warning when mousing-over it "C6386: Buffer overrun while writing to '*buf'". The buffer doesn't overrun, so I don't know the reason for this, any ideas? For (2) I get no such message, perhaps because, as you said, this is the same as setting the elements to NULL. The code still needs to be cleaned up and tested a bit more.

I don't understand the comment "No, you don't" from wildplasser about if (*buf == NULL), what does this mean? If for some reason the memory is failed to be allocated, I want to return immediately with a negative number to indicate failure - many thanks.