# Can I use a CreatNode function to return a struct rather than its steps repeated in All other functions?

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, singly-linked-list, pass-by-value, function-definition

I want to make a CreatNode() function in C to be called by other functions. I am playing around with code trying to reach great readability and functionality. The professor has a CreatEmptyList() function but not a CreatNode().She is negligent and not the capable of the concepts and C lagnguage and didn't give me an answer.

I don't need this exploration and trying ideas that come to my mind to pass the course, but my aim is to become a **Dev** not to **graduate**.

This is the code of the Prof:

```
typedef struct nodetype
{
    int info;
    struct nodetype *next;
} node;
    node *head;

void createemptylist(node *head)
{
    head=NULL;
}

void insertatbeginning(node *head, int item)
{
    node *newNode;
    /* allocate memory for the new node and initialize the data in it*/
    newNode= malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->info=item;
    /* assign the value of head to the “next” of newNode*/
    newNode->next=head;
    /* assign the address of newNode to head */
    head=newNode;
}

void insertatend(node *head, int item)
{
    node *newNode;
    newNode=malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->info=item;
    newNode->next=NULL;
    if(head==NULL)
      head=newNode;
    else
    {
     node *prev=head;
     while(prev->next!=NULL)
     prev=prev->next;
     prev->next=newNode;
    }
}
```

All are the snippets from the PDF she provided not exactly a compilable code.

This is the code I am working on and it keeps giving errors:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

    typedef struct Node{
        int info;
        struct Node *Next;
    }ListNode;

    ListNode CreatNode(ListNode *Head){///These steps not to be repeated using this function
        printf("\n=================\nEntered CreatNode Function");
        ListNode *NewNode;
        NewNode = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));

        return *NewNode;
    }

    void CreatList(ListNode *Head){
        printf("\n=================\nEntered CreatList Function");
        Head = NULL;
    }


    void InserBeg(ListNode *Head, int item){
        ///CreatNode() steps here

        NewNode=CreatNode(&Head);
        NewNode->info = item; ///Inesrt value
        NewNode->Next = Head;///Insert Adress inside Head to the Next point


        Head = NewNode;
        printf("\nFinished InsertBeg Function");
        printf("\nValue inserted is: %d\n=================\n", NewNode->info);
    }

    void Append(ListNode *Head, int item){
        ///CreatNode() steps here
        ///NewNode=CreatNode(Head);
        NewNode ->info = item;
        NewNode ->Next = NULL;
        
        if (Head==NULL){
            Head=ListNode
        }
        else{
            ListNode *Prev=Head;
            while(while->Prev!=NULL){
                Prev = Prev->Next;
            }
            Prev->Next=NewNode;
        }


    }



int main(){
    ListNode *Head;

    CreatList(&Head);
    InserBeg(&Head, 8);


    return 0;
}
```

errors:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\all\C\Single Linked List test.c|27|error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'ListNode * {aka struct Node *}' from type 'ListNode {aka struct Node}'|

Undeclared NewNode struct errors since it can't see it
```

Any help on coding my idea in different ways or make my code work?

Comment: Your program have this issue: [C Programming: malloc() inside another function - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838038/c-programming-malloc-inside-another-function) (not duplicate because there are other issues)

Comment: @LibyaChampion – What's the point of passing `&Head` to `CreatNode`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided by the professor code is very bad.

For starters she uses a global variable `head`. As the variable is declared in the file scope then it is already initialized as a null pointer. So this function

```
void createemptylist(node *head)
{
    head=NULL;
}
```

does not make a great sense. And moreover it does nothing with the original pointer `head` because it accepts its argument by value. That is it deals with a copy of the value of the original pointer.

By this reason other functions `insertatbeginning` and `insertatend` are wrong  because they do not change the original pointer `head` that they accept by value.

```
void insertatbeginning(node *head, int item)
{
    //...
    head=newNode;
}

void insertatend(node *head, int item)
{
    //...
    head=newNode;
    //...
}
```

They change a copy of the value of the original pointer.

The same problem is present in your functions.

As for the function `CreatNode` then as is it does not make a sense.

```
ListNode CreatNode(ListNode *Head){///These steps not to be repeated using this function
    printf("\n=================\nEntered CreatNode Function");
    ListNode *NewNode;
    NewNode = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));

    return *NewNode;
}
```

For starters the parameter `head` is not used within the function.  You need to pass an integer argument to the function that will be used as an initializer for the data member `info`.

Instead of an object of the type `ListNode` you should return a pointer to the dynamically allocated object. Otherwise the function returns a copy of the dynamically allocated object and as a result the function will produce a memory leak.

Within the functions `InserBeg` and `Append` the name `NewNode` is undefined as for example

```
void InserBeg(ListNode *Head, int item){
    ///CreatNode() steps here

    NewNode=CreatNode(&Head);
    //...
```

And you are calling the functions passing expressions of incompatible pointer type `ListNode **` instead of `ListNode *`.

```
CreatList(&Head);
InserBeg(&Head, 8);
```

Here is a demonstration program that shows how the function `CreateNode` and for example `InsertBeg` can be defined.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    int info;
    struct Node *next;
} ListNode;

ListNode * CreateNode( int info )
{
    ListNode *new_node = malloc( sizeof( *new_node ) );

    if ( new_node != NULL )
    {
        new_node->info = info;
        new_node->next = NULL;
    }

    return new_node;
}

int InsertBeg( ListNode **head, int info )
{
    ListNode *new_node = CreateNode( info );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->next = *head;
        *head = new_node;
    }

    return success;        
}

int main( void )
{
    ListNode *head = NULL;

    if ( InsertBeg( &head, 10 ) )
    {
        puts( "New node is added." );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "Error: not enough memory." );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
New node is added.
```

Comment: what is the point behind the line `int success = new_node != NULL;` and what about the function Append? if i am to creat a Node at the end will it be the same steps?